# Is Goddess Mahakali stated to be superior to Lord Vishnu in Sruti?

Tags: vishnu, upanishads, shakti, sruti

Certain Shaktas (followers of the Goddess, ie Shakti) used to quote verses from some Upanishads on Goddess Mahakali and her relation to the Lord Vishnu/Narayana/Krishna.
Thus they quote the Devi Upanishad also known as Devi Atharvashirsha Upanishad which belongs to the Atharva Veda:

> **I uphold** Soma, Tvastir, Pusan and Bhaga,
>   The wide-stepping **Vishnu**,
>   Brahma, Prajapati.

Other verses they quote are from the Bahvricha Upanishad of the Rig Veda:

> Om. The Goddess was indeed one in the beginning. Alone she emitted the
>   world-egg. (She) is known as Love’s Part (IM) [Kamakala]. (She) is known as the
>   half-syllabic instant after OM.
>   **Of Her** was Brahma born; **was Vishnu born**; was Rudra born.

Obviously Shaktas and Vaishnavas interpret these verses differently.

But my question is, what do Bhashyas say about these verses and what they reveal about Goddess Mahakali's relationship to the Lord Vishnu? Do these verses state any possible superiority of the Goddess over Lord Vishnu? Note that I'm not asking what users think the meaning of these verses is, just what Bhashya have to say.

Comment: This is an opinion-based question, because you're posting some scriptural verses, discussing how different sects of Hinduism interpret them, and then asking people's opinion on which interpretation is correct.  That's not what this site is for, so I'm closing your question for the time being.  If you want to edit your question into a factual question, like "What does group X think about these verses?", then I'd be happy to reopen it.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Would it be enough just to delete the last sentence, then? Actually my intention is not to ask people which interpretation is correct. I just want to hear what the answers I can get.

Comment: No, that wouldn't be enough.  You basically need to ask the question in a way that doesn't depend on the belief system of the person answering it.  If you want to modify the question into "How do Vaishnavas interpret these verses?" or "How do Shaktas interpret these verses?" that would be acceptable.

Comment: You can even ask "What do Rig Veda Bhashyas say about this verse?"

Comment: It is better you edit the title according to the edited sentence also. That might give rise to debates and discussions in the comments which do not help in getting  answer.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma The title is just fine.

Comment: I edited your question further and I reopened it.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Ok then those excluded parts from my Q, perhaps, I think I will post in my own answer later, but not before I see first some answers by our members. I hope you don't have any objections on that. I mean, what I wrote there was consistent with thoughts presented in the books by the Vedantists who commented on the verses from some other Upanishads, but are similar to those two which I quoted from the Bahvricha and Devi Atharvashirsha Upanishads.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan One more thing, I think the title of the Q can be original like I posted it. There was no problem with it, it was just fine. See, the purpose of the Q was focused exactly on that thing, namely whether is there some kind of superiority stated in the quoted verses or not. This is the crux of the problem, and the Q is here to deal with it.

Comment: @brahmajijnasa The thing is that people often just read the title of a question without reading the body.  So they may see the title asking about whether Vishnu or Mahakali is superior and then give their personal opinion on who is superior.  That's what we want to avoid.

Comment: @brahmajijnasa And I hope your answer is going to quote what Bhashyas say about these verses, since that is what the question is now.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Yeah, we should explain things according to the tradition. And regarding the title I think we shouldn't underestimate people. There is no need to be worried. Or should we put some pop-up window near the title which will detect every time when someone reads the title, and as soon as a person starts reading, the window would display a message "Warning! Dear readers you should read the whole question ...", something like that? (just kidding)

Comment: @brahmajijnasa Yes, I have it.  We can discuss this further in our chat room.

Comment: Nice question.. waiting for your answer @brahmajijnasa

Comment: @brahmajijnasa I think no one will attempt, I also have similar doubts, can you post your answer?

Comment: @RaRa & Dr.Vineet Yes, I can write an answer but my laptop is in coma and I'm writing on my smartphone which is difficult thing to do, so I will require time for writing and I have to find some quotations from the scriptures, all this need a lot of time.

Comment: @brahmajijnasa any chances that it will come out of coma in near future?

Comment: @RaRa I'm not sure about it, it's almost dead :) perhaps I should get a new one.